# tikzpicture, draw line starting from text area corner

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a line with TikZ from the top left corner of the text area, but a gap appears both horizontally and vertically. I specified `\noindent`, but there is still a gap.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (0,0) {+};
    \draw (0,0)--(\textwidth,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** it should be noted that it is because of the preceding `\node at (0,0) {+};` that `\draw (0,0)--(\textwidth,0);` starting position is displaced from the text area's top left corner.

I'm wondering is there is no way to define a canvas from top left corner to `(10, -10)` for example, and have robust coordinate system. This way would avoid the use of "overlay" and "remember picture".

In my original document the `tikzpicture` starts with a rectangle anchored at north and at `(.5\textwidth,0)`, and there are other drawings, and `textboxes` placed relatively to it. The problem is that the whole `tikzpicture` is slightly less wide than `\textwidth`, therefore everything is slightly away from the center, horizontally. `TikZ` handles the whole `tikzpicture` like an image and places it in the top left corner of the text area or just next to the preceding object, text...

Comment: isn't it better to globaly position that?A line of width `\textwidth` plus the space after the `tikzpicture` is wider than the text width and so things happen. Perhaps you should look up `overlay` and `remember picture` options for `tikzpicture`

Comment: both have coordinates (0,0). Just because of the "+" tikz displaced the actual position with coordinates (0,0).

Comment: there are numerous ways for "robust", page related coordinates, you can for example use the shipout hooks or the eso-pic package or the tikzpagenodes mentioned below.  But normally you don't want to place a picture relative to the page but relative to surrounding text and so that is the default behaviour of tikzpictures.

Comment: i wanted to avoid tikzpagenodes it makes the code longer. Indeed long sentences like "current page text area.north" just to say (.5\textwidth,0), and on top of that it requires running latex twice.

Answer (score 3):

Every node has certain size and some outer separation. In following example you can see how your node is well positioned, but the `+` is not where you want.

As an alternative you can draw using page nodes (with `tikzpagenodes` package) and forget manual positioning of nodes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[draw, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {+};
    \draw (0,0)--(\textwidth,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[blue, line width=2pt] (current page text area.north west)--(current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]